# How to design a logo like this one

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, illustration

I need to know how to design a logo like this one in **Adobe Illustrator**

[image: Logo of **Hodler- Coin Market Cap & Cryptocurrency Rates**]

**Especially the row wise color pattern and the material design effect**. Hope someone could help me with AI designing steps.

thank you

Comment: What is your Illustrator experience? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @mayersdesign I have designed some logos by myself(as a hobby for self satisfaction or to set as my mobile wallpaper)  by self learning Adobe Illistrator(little) and am not a good designer though! Pardon my bad English. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making something resembling in Illustrator is actually a challenging job for a beginner This needed some tinkering(due lousy thinking) but it at least resembles the wanted shape.

Note: the screenshots have a little faded colors due my poor system.

[image]

Let's dissasemble it. On the top there's a square with a hole. One can make it by aligning a square and a circle and making a compound path (Object > Compound path > Make)

[image]

The white shapes (mirrored J and L) are intentionally different than the model. It resembles the S in the well hated SS symbol and some angles are nearly the same as in the swastika. I reduced radically the number of equalities. The white shapes are rotated rectangles which are united in the Pathfinder panel. The shadow is the same shape with black fill, reduced opacity and a little exaggerated Gaussian Blur effect

[image]

The long throw shadow is drawn with the Pen, it has grey fill, reduced opacity and Gaussian Blur effect

[image]

The bottom shapes got too high contrast. A reduced opacity red gradient was added to flatten it. If the bottom shapes and their coloring plates had been made more carefully and cleverly (as a symbol and as a gradient, not 3D, the contrast flattener maybe would be unnecessary)

[image]

The background has 5 differently colored slices. The shading is BW, so coloring rectangles with blending mode Hard Light were added

[image]

The bottom shapes are equal. They started as a curve, drawn with the pen, they got grey color and 3D effect Extrude & Bevel.

The effect settings were adjusted until the size, watching direction and the shading were accaptable. The screenshot is an early version which had lower contrast than the used one. Too high contrast was not considered bad because I knew it can be flattened. It's possible with the direct selection tool also adjust the curve and see the result as extruded. The extrusion depth in the next image is low to make it fit to the high zoom screenshot. You set it the same as the wanted final width.

[image]